# How can I fix this error : This is related to npm not being able to find a file npm run start

Tags: npm

I've changed the names of the files where I have my projects. When I run npm start on one of them I got the error below:

npm ERR! errno -4058

npm ERR! enoent spawn bash ENOENT

**npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.**

npm ERR! enoent

I've deleted node_modules manually then I run npm Install(window) but it didn't fix the problem.

How can I solve that, please?

Comment: Try updating your npm version. [Npm Docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/common-errors#many-enoent--enotempty-errors-in-output)

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: Have you tried running the command as an elevated user?